# RealityKit second animation resets animation of a different entity

Tags: ios, swift, realitykit

I am creating a falling animation for a box entity. When I tap on a box, another box falls from above to land on top of it. This animation works fine. But, if I tap a second box during the animation of a previous box's fall, both the animations restart, and both boxes fall. Any idea how to prevent this? Seems that the scene is resetting the position of the previous animation because it hasn't been completed yet.

```
    func fall(to finalPosition: SIMD3<Float>) {
        guard isFalling == false
        else {
            print("already falling")
            return
        }
        
        isFalling = true
        
        var finalTransform = Transform()
        finalTransform.translation = finalPosition
        
        var startPosition = finalPosition
        startPosition.y = finalPosition.y + 20
        
        var startTransform = Transform()
        startTransform.translation = startPosition
        
        transform = startTransform
        
        let duration: Double = 2.0
        animationController = move(to: finalTransform, relativeTo: parent, duration: duration)
        
        print("starting fall")
        
        finishSub = scene?.subscribe(
            to: AnimationEvents.PlaybackCompleted.self,
            on: self,
            { (event: AnimationEvents.PlaybackCompleted) in
                guard event.playbackController == self.animationController
                else {
                    print("different controller, not ending fall")
                    return
                }
                print("ending fall")
                self.isFalling = false
            }
        )
    }
```

Here is the output for a single box

```
    starting fall
    already falling
    ending fall
```

And here is when two are pressed quickly

```
    starting fall
    already falling
    starting fall
    already falling
    ending fall
    ending fall
```